# Strange Issues with ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2

PLEASE HELP, something seems not to be working here,I previously ploted this figure and it was working fine, however, now it seems something is off.
The categories are no longer orderly and some of them appear twice...

...[image]

```
ggplot(data = data_c, aes(x = reorder(Sektor, -Preis), y = Preis)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = data_c$Menge/26) +
geom_line(data = data_c, aes(group = 1, x = Sektor, 
                           y =  Preis, colour = "40 € pro MWh")) +
geom_line(data = data_d, aes(group = 1, x = sektoren2, 
                           y =  preise2, colour = "60 € pro MWh")) +
geom_label(aes(label = preise2a), nudge_y = 30, size = 4) +
geom_label(aes(label = twh2), nudge_y = 6, size = 4) +
geom_text(aes(label = euros), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white", size = 2) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(suffix = " €", prefix = "")) +
labs(title = "Merrit Order Curve Wasserstoff",
   subtitle = "Mengen in TWh und Preise in Euro pro MWh",
   x = "Sektoren", 
   y = "Preise in Euro pro MWh") +
theme_bw()
```

´´´

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, i already solved the problem ;)